# How to implement scoped iostream formatting?

Tags: c++, formatting, scope, iostream

I'd like to scope-limit the effect of I/O stream formatting in C++, so that I can do something like this:

```
std::cout << std::hex << ...
if (some_condition) {
  scoped_iofmt localized(std::cout);

  std::cout << std::oct << ...
}
// outside the block, we're now back to hex
```

so that base, precision, fill, etc. are restored to their previous values upon leaving the block.

Here's the best I've come up with:

```
#include <ios>

class scoped_iofmt
{
    std::ios& io_;     // The true stream we shadow
    std::ios  dummy_;  // Dummy stream to hold format information

    public:
    explicit scoped_iofmt(std::ios& io)
                : io_(io), dummy_(0) { dummy_.copyfmt(io_); }
    ~scoped_iofmt() { try { io_.copyfmt(dummy_); } catch (...) {} }
};
```

... but c++ iostreams are a rather thorny area, and I'm not sure of the safety/appropriateness of the above.  Is it dangerous?  Have you (or has a third party) already done better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like the Boost [I/O Stream State-saver library](http://www.boost.org/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html)?